# How to get id with content of StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>> when creating a List with snapshot

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-streambuilder

I'm using geoflutterfire() to get some datas. It works fine but for a part of my app, I would like to send only a List to another screen without calling again firebase.

I do :
`

```
 GeoFirePoint maposition =
        geofire.point(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude);

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> streamg = Geoflutterfire()
        .collection(collectionRef: refe)
        .within(
            center: maposition,
            radius: cercle.toDouble(),
            field: 'pos',
            strictMode: true);
```

`

and
`

```
return StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
        stream: streamg,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        ...
        

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
             
           ...
              List<Object?> laListeDesExpires =
                snapshot.data!.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
           ... 

          }
```

`

With this method, I get all the datas and I can pass everything to the other page EXCEPT the *snapshot.data!.id*

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot

I tried
`

```
  List<Object?> laListeDesExpires =
                snapshot.data!.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
```

`

and I expect to get the document id

Comment: is the id not included in your object model? if not then you have to include it for convenience.

Comment: That's the point. How to add the doc id? :)

Comment: just add 'id' in your model. ex. `Product(id: id, title: title, price: price...etc)`

Comment: humpf ! It works :)
Thank you John